# Angular2 call function in another function with same class and use first functions property in second

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 functions in a class, both class getting data from API calls.

Here is the **First function**

```
getQuotes(){
    this.quoteService.getQuotes()
    .subscribe(
      quotes => {
        this.quotCode = this.quotes.BasicDetails[0].QuotCode;
        }
      });
}
```

**Second Function**

```
getOption(){
    this.quoteService.getOptions()
    .subscribe(
            options => {
     })
}
```

I want to get data from this line from first function

```
this.quotCode = this.quotes.BasicDetails[0].QuotCode;
```

and based on `this.quotCode` `getOption()` will have different params to pass and will get diff. response also. so it is necessary to use `this.quotCode` in second function

I'm calling `getQuotes()` in `constuctor()`

Can anyone please help me out?
Thanks

Comment: @trichetriche can you please help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RXJS](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) `mergeMap` is the operator you need : this way, you will execute the second request once the first one succeeds.

```
this.quoteService.getQuotes().mergeMap( quotes => {
    // Do whatever you need to do with quotes
    return this.quoteService.getOptions()
}).subscribe( options => {
    // Do whatever you need with options
});
```

Comment: Okay,let me try

Comment: it works but sometime `getOptions` doesn't load at all even if first loads